# Disabling dark mode via CSS or browser not working as expected

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, darkmode

I have dark mode enabled on my system (osx 13.4 (22F66)). For the test web browsers, I am running Chrome (114.0.5735.106) and Firefox (114.0.1).

A web application I am working on seems to have the system dark mode setting applied to it. The result is that some elements are inverted, and not others, so I am unable to reliably see all elements in the site without highlighting/selecting them, which is frustrating.

This is occurring despite:

1. Using `chrome://flags` to forceably disable dark mode within all of Chrome.
2. Applying `color-scheme: only light` at the root of the document CSS for the specific web application.

Neither step seems to get the site rendered the way it would look if I disabled dark mode at an operating-system level.

*Other than changing how my system is configured*, what other things can I try that would disable what dark mode settings are doing to this site, specifically within the browser, or just for this site itself? Are there any Javascript calls I can make, CSS styles I can add, or other hidden browser configuration windows available?

Comment: "Applying color-scheme: only light at the root of the document CSS for the specific web application." — That is for writing CSS rules that apply *only* when the browser is set to *light* mode.

Comment: I went back to V113 until they fix this (and I will stay at this version until they fix this)

Comment: Thanks, Temani. This is making development difficult, for sure. I'll look at reverting.